# Output directory name from linux find command

Tags: linux

How do I get the name of a folder from a linux find commnad.

I have  a command like this:

```
find /root/wgetlog -name -type d -empty
```

Whic produces the following results:

```
/root/wgetlog/smil3
/root/wgetlog/smil5
/root/wgetlog/smil4
```

how do I get just the name of the folder:

Example:
smil3
smil4
smil5

Answer (score 2):

`find /root/wgetlog -type d -empty -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: Oops, remove the -name that I copied from your question.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is a relative path, then

```
 { pushd /root/wgetlog/; find . -name -type d -empty; popd; }
```

is the approach, especially if you do care about subdirectories of /root/wgetlog/*.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**`basename`**](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/basename/):

```
find /root/wgetlog -type d -empty -exec basename {} \;
```

You don't need `-name`.

Comment: That didnt work: 
find: paths must precede expression
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [path...] [expression]

Comment: @wademills: Did you remove ` -name`?

Comment: [root@385872-TEST wgetlog]# find /root/wgetlog -type d -empty -exec basename {} \
find: missing argument to `-exec'

Comment: You need the semicolon (`;`).

Comment: @wademills: You're welcome. Note that "That worked. Thanks" is best expressed on StackOverflow ["by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sed` to filter out the leading elements of each path:

```
$ find /usr/bin -type d 
/usr/bin
/usr/bin/multiarch-i386-linux
/usr/bin/multiarch-x86_64-linux
/usr/bin/gda_trml2pdf
/usr/bin/gda_trml2html
...
$ find /usr/bin -type d | sed 's|.*/||'
bin
multiarch-i386-linux
multiarch-x86_64-linux
gda_trml2pdf
gda_trml2html
...
```

This might be more portable than using the `-printf` option of `find`, although that should not be an issue if you stick to Linux.

Disclaimer: this will fail horribly if you have newlines in your file/folder names. On the other hand, this snippet is probably not the only thing that would fail in that case...